# Trying to turn all of my posts into a soundcloud playlist and can't figure out where to start

Tags: audio, html5

I have a music blog, and each post contains a soundcloud player.  I am designing the site, and would like to find a way to turn all of the posts into a "radio station" or playlist of sorts.  Whereas if you click "next," it will play the next song in the next post.  Additionally, if you are viewing a category archive, such as "new releases".. the player would play all of the songs from that category.

The player will be a sticky player, but will need to interact with the posts as well.  I will NOT be using a single post page... all posts will be full content on the main page.

Any thoughts?  Initially i was trying to implement code that would write the link of the soundcloud embed to an xml, and create an HTML5 playlist from that xml file.    But I don't think I can make a playlist from the soundcloud embeds.

Perhaps I should just write js that when an html5 song ends, it goes to the next post and autoplays the next html5 player.  Does this make sense?  I am much more of a designer than a coder!

Hypem.com does this very well!

Answer (score 0):

I would use Custom Meta Post Boxes as seen in this tutorial:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

You can add your own "Soundcloud ID" field which is entered in each post in a separate box. That will expose the needed data to your theme files in a much easier way. From here you can adjust your single post and archive templates to include the embedded soundcloud player using the provided ID.

If you want a radio station with all the posts you can just loop through the IDs using the archive. Don't forget to increase the post limit if you want all songs to appear.

Comment: Please don't only use links as answer. Your answer should cover everything that is needed to solve the question, without following a link. If the link is dead, so is your answer and as this is no forum, but answers should serve as a reference, please [edit] it and show how to make this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help @curtisbelt.  I don't see how this could help it automatically play the soundcloud in the next post?

Comment: I'm working with Soundcloud custom player at the moment... https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player.  It seems it should work.  I successfully converts the link into an html5 player...  but unfortunately it isn't seeing the next track....  maybe because its in the loop and not actually in the html?